# what is best SQLite Db path for all devices

Tags: android, database, sqlite, path, runtimeexception

I  change the SQLite database path in my program from this way:`

> public EDataHelper(Context context) {
>          super(context,"/mnt/sdcard/E_Data/E.db", null, version);

I didn't have any problem with some devices
but recently I understand in some devices this doesn't work and I get :
 **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database error**

after I change code into:`super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);` it works
but I want to change Db path..
anyone can help me which way for setting a path works in all device?
thanks for any help
`

Comment: Use a valid path. `/mnt/sdcard/E_Data/` does not exist on every one of the ~2 billion Android devices. You have not had arbitrary write access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) for years.

Comment: In particular, **never hardcode paths**. Always use methods to derive paths from roots (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`).